# Issues not working on private gitlab instance

Tags: nginx, gitlab, reverse-proxy, gitlab-omnibus

I have gitlab running behind a nginx reverse proxy on a relative url (`my.domain.com/gitlab/`) in a docker container. I've migrated some of my projects from Github and everything seemed fine. However when I tried to see details for an existing issue, which was migrated with the project, the website didn't load. It looked like the reverse proxy was routing back to `<server-ip-address>:<port>` again, instead of the url. I also tested what happens when I create a new issue, because I thought maybe the migration didn't work, but it had the same effects. After a bit more testing I figured that typing in the issue-number in the url works though e.g. `my.domain.com/gitlab/group-name/project-name/-/issues/4`.

I'm really confused now, whether this is a problem with nginx or gitlab itself. Did anyone have similar issues?

Gitlab-Version: `gitlab/gitlab-ce:14.10.0-ce.0`

Nginx: `nginx:1.21.6-alpine`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just downgraded Gitlab to version `gitlab/gitlab-ce:14.9.4-ce.0` and it works. So I guess this is a problem with the other version and has absolutely nothing to do with docker or nginx.